# Does "stray off" equal "stray away from"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

For example:

> Carelessly roaming around the public square, I strayed **off the way** home.

Can I paraphrase it like this:

> Carelessly roaming around the public square, I strayed **away from the way** home.

Comment: Can't a dictionary answer your question?

Comment: @VictorBazarov The four dictionaries I consulted (Collins, Oxford, M-W, AHD) give no explicit guidance on this topic. If you carefully review all the examples given in all four, you might infer that "stray away from the way" is acceptable, but there is nothing to tell you whether that is equivalent to "stray off the way".

Comment: I think it is better to say, ". . . I went astray on my way home". "Go astray" suits your context IMO.

Answer (score 1):

*Stray off X* is not really a phrasal verb, it means what it says literally.  One typically *strays off* a known path, course, or defined area.

So by saying this:

> I strayed off the way home.

you are

- assuming the listener/reader knows what "the way home" is and that it's a known path or course you take home, or:
- indirectly telling the listener/reader there is such a known path or course you take home.

Comment: So the "stray off" is grammatically correct,right?

Comment: It is grammatically correct.